# Syntax for using overloaded operator C++

Tags: c++, syntax, operator-overloading, inline

This is an overloaded operator contained in a class:

```
inline operator const FOO() const { return _obj_of_type_FOO; }
```

I cannot for the life of me understand:

- How I would invoke this operator?
- What would be its return value?
- [Secondary] Whether making it **inline** affects anything apart from efficiency?

Comment: What is `FOO`?  A macro?  A type?

Comment: @mital_91 Its return type is const FOO.

Comment: It won't compile. The operator is returning a function either way, not allowed in the standard. Except if some evil wizard `#define`'d 'const' to be some kind of hocus-pocus @5gon12eder

Comment: @WorldSEnder  I thought that it is braces. I think it is a typo.

Comment: @WorldSEnder No, it is returning a `const FOO`. It is a conversion operator.

Comment: @everyone: FOO is a type.

Comment: @juanchopanza, no: http://ideone.com/pClXrl

Comment: @WorldSEnder Ah yes, I missed the trailing `()`.

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect prototype fellas. Please check the EDITS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That expression looks like a declaration of a conversion operator if Foo is a type and it is inside a class.  The second `const` (the one closer to the opening curly bracket) means that the conversion can be called on `const` instances.  Let us say the class is C.  You can think of a conversion operator as a constructor outside a class.  For example, you can't add constructors to the class std::string, but you can add a conversion operator to std::string to your classes.  The result is that you can construct std::string from your class instance.

1) How to invoke the conversion operator: by constructing a value of type Foo from a C, for example:
`Foo foo = c` (where c is an instance of C, the class that declares the conversion operator).  Mind you that the invocation of the conversion can happen implicitly.  If you have, for example, `void funOnFoo(Foo v);` and an instace `c` of `C`, this might implicitly call `operator const Foo`: `funOnFoo(c)`. Whether this actually does, depends on the usual things: Whether there are other overloads of `funOnFoo`, other conversions for `C`, etc.

2) The return value is `const Foo`

3) `inline` means the same thing as for any function, in particular, does not affect overload resolution